# ChaiJS jsonSchema check for multiple types

Tags: javascript, postman, schema, chai

In my Chai-Test (using it for PostMan) I want to validate my API-response-design. For that I have written a Chai-Test:

```
pm.test("Check response schema", () => {
    const schema = {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "success": { "type": "boolean" },
            "data": { "type": "object" },
            "err": { "type": "object" },
            "info": { "type": "string" }
        },
        "required": ["success", "data", "err", "info"]
    }
    pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(schema)
})
```

My problem now is, that either the `data` or the `err` object is defined based on whether the request to the API was successful or not. I wanted to accomplish that by using two types for the `data`  and the `err`: object AND null. So, how can I check for two types with the jsonSchema? Or is there an other and better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that:

```
"data": { "type": ["object", "null"] },
"err": { "type": ["object", "null"] }
```